# Unable to create Build for App Store submission

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I have manually added Kingfisher in my iOS project. Project runs on my iPhone device. But when I try to make a archived build, it give too much errors. I am using MacBook Air Silicon series.

Reproduce

Add Kingfisher manually in a project.
Try to Archive the project
This is where I added Kingfisher

[image]

Errors I am receiving.
[image]

Comment: Close Xcode. Go to `Applications > Xcode > right click > Get Info > Open using Rosetta`. Open Xcode, try archiving now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added Kingfisher again using Swift Package Manager and it started working perfectly.

For a detailed conversation with the maintainer, check the issue below

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/1727

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is any inconsistency in your ios Deployment target. If you sub project (here kingfisher) deployment target is higher than your main project it may build for your device but not archieve. As when it is archieving it is building for all devices.